# Manage all path formats with Python

Tags: python

It's basic (but not simple) topic with Python and I can't find a generic solution.

That I would like to do is to manage all possible path formats by passing one path to a function and get a main format with /

Example :

```
print ("P1.a="+convertPath ('D:\2-test\plop1\3_plop_2\O M G\tools'))
print ("P1.b="+convertPath ("D:\2-test\plop1\3_plop_2\O M G\tools"))
print ("P2.a="+convertPath ('D:\\2-test\\plop1\\3_plop_2\\O M G\\tools'))
print ("P2.b="+convertPath ("D:\\2-test\\plop1\\3_plop_2\\O M G\\tools"))
print ("P3.a="+convertPath ('D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools'))
print ("P3.b="+convertPath ("D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools"))
```

Output :

```
P1.a=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
P1.b=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
P2.a=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
P2.b=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
P3.a=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
P3.b=D:/2-test/plop1/3_plop_2/O M G/tools
```

I wrote this function and it works with the previous example (output was generated by this function) :

```
def convertPath (path):

  # Convert string to raw string
  retval = "%r"%path
    
  # Remove special characters
  retval = retval.replace("\\x0", '/')
  retval = retval.replace('\\', '/')
  
  # Replace \ and \\ by /
  retval = retval.replace('\\', '/')
  retval = retval.replace("//", '/')
  retval = retval.replace("//", '/')

  # Remove '
  retval = retval[1:-1]
  
  return retval
```

But I have a problem with on another type of path, with \v replaced by \b

Input :

```
print ("P4.a="+convertPath ('C:\vabcdef\5_test\99-test2\projTest\execution\test.yml'))
```

Output :

```
P4.a=C:/babcdef/5_test/99-test2/projTest/execution/test.yml
```

So It's not a robust solution. Have you a generic solution for that ?

Note :

- I cannot force user to use directly the good format
- I cannot force user to use r"my\path\with\v\or\b"
- I tried to write/read path in/from a file, without success

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib)?

Comment: There is no generic solution possible - some of the transformations that result when you put inappropriate backslashes in a non-raw string literal are irreversible.  For example, writing `\x41` in such a string produces an `A`, fundamentally indistinguishable from an actual `A` in the string - no post-processing that you can possibly do will fix this.

Comment: @noslenkwah : yes but I didn't find a solution or workaround with that.

Comment: @jasonharper : ok, I understand, so I haven't a clean solution, If I would like to manage this situation, I must use a "very dirty" way. I understood the technical reason but I'm really surprised, it means none developer user must follow Python rules when he puts path into a configuration file or when he calls a script for example.